# Replace part of URL using Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace a part of the url with another string in javascript, so for example i have the following:

```
res/icons/android/quickshop/icon-36-ldpi.png
res/icons/android/quickshop/icon-48-mdpi.png
res/icons/ios/quickshop/icon-72-hdpi.png
res/icons/ios/quickshop/icon-96-xhdpi.png
```

and I want to replace it to the following (quickshop is dynamic and can be any series of characters, mostly [a-z][A-Z])

```
res/icons/android/homecenter/icon-36-ldpi.png
res/icons/android/homecenter/icon-48-mdpi.png
res/icons/ios/homecenter/icon-72-hdpi.png
res/icons/ios/homecenter/icon-96-xhdpi.png
```

I was always very lousy when it comes to regular expressions, anyone could help?

Comment: @Shafizadeh yup one string per line, i thought i would put 4 examples to illustrate

Comment: Ok, what language are you using?

Comment: @Shafizadeh Javascript

Comment: @Shafizadeh updated the question to clarify it a bit

Comment: I'm not sure I get you right, do you want something like this: https://regex101.com/r/pF1nY9/3

Comment: @Shafizadeh that was fast thanks, now that i matched them how can i replace them in javascript

Comment: I will write an answer ..!

Comment: really, you should be using a rewrite rule in your htaccess file for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var str    = "res/icons/android/quickshop/icon-36-ldpi.png\nres/icons/android/quickshop/icon-48-mdpi.png\nres/icons/ios/quickshop/icon-72-hdpi.png\nres/icons/ios/quickshop/icon-96-xhdpi.png",
    result = str.replace(/([\w.-]+)(\/[\w.-]+)$/gm,"homecenter$2");
console.log(result);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/(([\w]+\/){3})([^\/]+)(\/.+)/gm
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF1nY9/4)

---

```
var re = /(([\w]+\/){3})([^\/]+)(\/.+)/gm; 
var str = 'res/icons/android/quickshop/icon-36-ldpi.png';
var replaceWord = 'homecenter'
var subst = '$1' + replaceWord + '$4';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
// show result
window.alert(result);
```

---

could even be written as a function:

```js
function replaceURL(url, strReplace){
    let re = /(([\w]+\/){3})([^\/]+)(\/.+)/gm; 
    var subst = '$1' + strReplace + '$4';
    return url.replace(re, subst);
}

var originalURL = 'res/icons/android/quickshop/icon-36-ldpi.png';
var replaceWord = 'homepage';

var newURL = replaceURL(originalURL, replaceWord);

document.write(newURL);
```

Comment: used the wrong references - see above (changed `\1` to `$1` etc)

Comment: All those URLs are one string per line.